# Working of "between" operator for Varchar and Char datatypes in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to use "between" operator on "varchar" and "char(5)" columns in a table. However, I don't see any effect of "between" operator in the results.

Please note that "code" is the column name

I have a table with a column of type VARCHAR and I apply cast operation to convert it into "CHAR(5)" type. When I apply between operator in the query on either of the columns, it doesn't produce a filtered result.

For VARCHAR COLUMN

```
select code from diagnoses where code between '4254' and 
'5855'
```

For CHAR(5) COLUMN

```
 select cast(code as char(5)) as code
 from diagnoses where code between '4254' and '5855'
```

I expect the output to have only records within this range but instead I get records which don't meet this criteria as well. Please find a sample screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=72bd76d31dd91dcefc0d820cab62cf6a)

The `BETWEEN` operator for character based types works for alphabetical order. That means it uses the order

```
4254
45829
486
...
58381
5845
5855
```

So the output is completely correct.

If you want a numeric order you have to cast it into an appropriate data type:

```
select 
    cast(code as char(5)) as code
from 
    diagnoses 
where 
    cast(code as int) between 4254 and 5855 -- cast here
```

Result:

```
4254
5119
5589
5845
5855
```

Comment: Only thing was I just have to use an expression to look for values with numbers and then apply the function as you suggested because there were few records which had alphabetes as well. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

I would write the logic like this:

```
where code::int between 4254 and 5855
```

Or, if you want to use an index:

```
where code between '4254' and '5855' and
      length(code) = 4
```